# Node mysql error event triggering on a connection that has been released back to the pool

Tags: mysql, node.js

**The Problem**

My issue is that even though I have released a connection back to the pool from a request using . . .

```
connection.release();
```

. . . I still get the following code triggering and logging an error after 60 seconds (I presume a pre defined timeout).

```
connection.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Error with connection:" + connection.threadId);
            return;
});
```

I'm pretty sure the connection is being released because if I remove the release lines and keep sending requests I can see different connections being used from the pool. The same connection appears to be used if I keep them in.

**The Route Code**

```
app.post('/addImageData', function (req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
            return;
        }

        writeToDatabaseLog("Image post request made with ID:" + connection.threadId, connection);

        uploadImageToCloudinary(req.body.image, connection)
            .then(function(rawData) {
                return addImageDataToDB(rawData, connection)
            }).then(function(imageURL) {
                return notifyIFTTTofImageCapture(imageURL, connection)
            }).then(function(){
                connection.release();
                res.send(200);
            }, function(){
                connection.release();
                res.send(500);
            });

        connection.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Error with connection:" + connection.threadId);
            return;
        });
    });

});
```

**My Bodge Fix**

I've tried reading the [API reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) on "Pooling connections" and "Error handling".

I've found that if I switch the three examples of . . .

```
connection.release()
```

. . . to . . .

```
connection.destroy()
```

. . . then the issue no longer happens.

I believe this is not the best solution as it deletes a connection from the pool. The API says a new connection will be created but it feels like this takes away from the point of a pool.

**What I Think I'm Not Getting**

The issue seems to be that even when a connection has been returned to the pool the event listener for an error is still active. However I don't know how to resolve this.

**Full code:**

This is my full code but does include the bodge fix described above.
https://github.com/tbenyon/suphomie/blob/de855c898065a50c119f66b3773a17012e3c3b8e/app.js

**Testing**

If you wanted to clone the repo and test this live there is an test python file called "testDoorBellClient.py" on this commit.

**Thank you**

This is my first question so if I've missed anything useful please let me know.

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense since the `mysql` module does not actively check for (and remove) event handlers added outside of the `mysql` module. So what you need to do is remove your handler before releasing the connection. For example:

```
connection.removeListener('error', onConnError);
connection.release();

// ...

function onConnError(err) {
  console.log("Error with connection:" + connection.threadId);
}
connection.on('error', onConnError);
```